# Как отобразить элемент перейдя по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день профи. Скажите, я сейчас использую функцию "спрятать таблицу" нажав по ссылке. Там где я вставляю `id="hide_this"` - элемент (таблица) исчезает.

Вопрос, а как мне сделать наоборот

- сперва таблица спрятана,
- а когда нажимаешь по ссылке -появляется?

Код:

```
function toggle() {
 if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = '';
 }else{
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
```

Ссылка:

```
<a href="#null" toggle() onclick="toggle()">Показать отделы:</a>
```

То что прячем:

```
<table id="hidethis">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте изначально в html для таблиц **style="display:none"**. При этом элементы будут изначально скрываться.

```
<table style="display:none" id="hidethis">
```

Comment: вы гений ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id=myTable class=hidden>...</table>
<a href="javascript:toggle();">toggle table</a>

.hidden{display:none; }

function toggle() { document.getElementById('myTable').classList.toggle('hidden'); }
```